# passing javascript actions within php while loop

Tags: php, javascript

I need the following functionality :

"When a checkbox is checked, the corresponding textbox must be highlighted and user could be able to enter some text into that.."

Checkboxes are working, but when a checkbox is checked, the corresponding textbox is not activating, how to solve this?

Here is my php code :

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('/year_no/albums')) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
            echo "<form name='form1'>
            <div class='controlset-pad'>
            <font color='black'><label><input type='checkbox' name='album[]' value='$album' onclick='enable_text(this.checked)' class='medium'/><span>$album</span></label><br/></div>​";
            echo"<script> 
            function enable_text(status)
            {
                status=!status;
                document.form1.other_name.disabled = status;
            }
            </script>";
            echo "<div class='field4'><label>Add your comment here</label><input type='text' name='other_name' class='medium' disabled='disabled'/></div></form>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

MODIFIED CODE:

```
<script> 
function enable_text(status, sub)
{
status=!status;
document.getElementById(sub).disabled = status;
}
</script>
<form name='form1'>
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('/year_no/albums')) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
echo "<div class='controlset-pad'>
<font color='black'><label><input type='checkbox' name='file[]' value='$file' onclick='enable_text(this.checked, $file)' class='medium'/><span>$file</span></label>
</div>";
echo "<div class='field4'><label>Add your comment here</label><input type='text' name='sub' id='$file' class='medium' disabled='disabled'/></div>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Use [heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or drop out of PHP mode to output large amounts of HTML.

Comment: The `font` tag is long deprecated. Use CSS instead.

Comment: Make sure to escape possibly unsafe strings, like `$album`, with a function like [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to prevent accidental (or malicious) XSS.

Comment: Why would you print a function n times?
You'll have to put the Javascript code in the header or footer of your page. Assign classes/ids to the checkboxes/textfields in your while loop, and write your JS code to use these ids/classes for doing stuff.

Comment: your code is also working on my system

Comment: because your `function enable_text()` is repeating through loop. and it won't work.

Comment: You have n - `enable_text()` functions, n - `form1` forms, and n - `other_name` text boxes. Since they are have the same name, how will javascript know which function to call, which form to select, and which text box to disable/enable?

Comment: @Sean - we have `$(this)` to get the attribute values.

Comment: @PankitKapadia So you are saying that the OP's nth `onclick='enable_text(this.checked)'` will select the nth `enable_text()` function, and the nth `form1` & `other_name` in `document.form1.other_name.disabled`? I believe that this is the issue, as none of the names for the function, form, or input are unique, so the `$(this)` is still not calling the correct nth function/field/text box.

Comment: @Sean Please check the modified code..

Comment: @Sean - you are getting me wrong. as i am also saying that it must be unique. i said *function is repeating through loop. so it won't work.*

Comment: @highlander141 - have you got the solution or should i post an answer?

Comment: @PankitKapadia pls post the answer- thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try This:**

*As you said, the below code has functionality that enables the textbox when checkbox is checked, and disables it again when it is unchecked.*

Here is a working [**Example:**](http://kapadiapankit.in/testhere.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">    </script>
<!-- include JQuery using above line -->

<!-- Here is your small javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click",function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    //If checkbox is checked do whatever you want to do here.
            $("#txt_"+$(this).attr("id")).removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#drpdwn_"+$(this).attr("id")).removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
                   // If unchecked.
            $("#txt_"+$(this).attr("id")).attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $("#drpdwn_"+$(this).attr("id")).attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<?php
$dir = "/year_no/albums";

if(is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        $blacklist = array('.', '..');
        $count=1;
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)){  
                echo "<div class='controlset-pad'>
                        <font color='black'>
                            <label>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='file[]' id='".$count."' value='enabletxtbox' class='medium'/>
                                <span>".$file."</span>
                            </label>
                    </div>";
                echo "<div class='field4'>
                        <label>Add your comment here</label>
                        <input type='text' name='sub' id='txt_".$count."' class='medium' disabled='disabled'/>";

                if(filetype($dir.$file) == "dir"){
                        $dir2 = $dir.$file;
                        $dh2=opendir($dir2);
                        $drpdwn="<select id='drpdwn_".$count."' disabled='disabled'>";
                        while(($file2 = readdir($dh2)) !== false){
                            if(!in_array($file2, $blacklist)){
                                $drpdwn.='<option>'.$file2.'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                        $drpdwn.="</select>";
                        closedir($dh2);
                        echo $drpdwn;

                }
                echo"</div>";
            }
            $count++;
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @highlander141 - pleasure ! NJoi !! :)

Comment: bro, i need some more info, can I get ur mail_id pls ?

Comment: thanks again, what I need actually is, check box is related to dir listing upto dir albums, later when a checkbox is chosen, in that associated textbox, a dropdown menu must appear which lists all the sub-dir's of chosen checkbox, can u plz guide me...

Comment: i am not getting you dude. what do you mean by `in that associated textbox, a dropdown menu must appear`??

Comment: when a checkbox is checked, in the place of activating textbox, we have to activate a dropdown list which contains the sub-dir of the chosen checkbox..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21675/discussion-between-highlander141-and-pankit-kapadia)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfect , just add a small change as followed.

Instead of `id`

```
document.getElementById('other_name').disabled = status;
```

Note that `id` must be unique for each elements.

Edit use this code

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('/year_no/albums')) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
echo "<form name='form1'>
<div class='controlset-pad'>
<font color='black'><label><input type='checkbox' name='album[]' value='$album' onclick='enable_text(this.checked, $album)' class='medium'/><span>$album</span></label><br/>
</div>?";
echo"<script> 
function enable_text(status, album)
{
status=!status;
document.getElementById(album).disabled = status;
}
</script>";
echo "<div class='field4'><label>Add your comment here</label><input type='text' name='other_name' id = '$album' class='medium' disabled='disabled'/></div></form>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Note that $album value can't be null

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you show me in the code where to add?

Comment: inside function enable_text()

Comment: yes i had modified, but the same problem, when checkbox is checked, the textbox is not activated..

Comment: @ManishGoyal - He is repeating `function enable_text()` in while loop. You can't define functions with same name as it won't work. While loop is defining same function with same name.

Comment: @highlander141 - are you comfortable with JQuery?

Comment: @PankitKapadia yes I am, is there any solution in jQuery ?

Comment: @highlander141 - yes it does have. but you will also need to change your `<html>` code in `PHP`, because your loop is creating multiple `<form>` tag with same name. Tell me what exactly you want to do? I mean after adding `comment` to the textbox.

Comment: The problem is not with javascript, actually your code clearly indicates that you simply showing text box for each album, hence if there will be many text box it won't work, since document.form.other_name is meant for single field only, instead of this you should rather use id

Comment: @ManishGoyal Thank you for ur comment, your code also doesnot seem to work, the same problem, textbox is not activating

Comment: @PankitKapadia Yes, first can we solve the Problem-1 that is activating the respective textbox after a checkbox has been selected?

Answer (score 2):

use this example

```
    <form name="form1">
    <script>
    function enable_text(status)
            {
            alert(status)
            status=!status;
            document.form1.other_name.disabled = status;
            }
    </script>
        <input type='checkbox' name='album' value='hi' onclick='enable_text(this.checked)' class='medium'/>
        <input type='text' name='other_name' class='medium' disabled='disabled'/>
    </form>
```